# Is it Possible to use the SQL IN operator targeting a column with text ('9','10')?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Table that includes a CountryPhoneLength column of a single character (VarChar Type - Maybe Numeric, doesn't matter)

```
CountryPhoneLength
9
8
7
```

And comparing that to a column in another Table called Param with Column PhoneLengthConfig that would be a string type and consist of '('9','8')' or the numeric equivalent  For example

```
PhoneLengthConfig
('9','8')
(9,8)
```

The SQL would be for example

```
SELECT column_name FROM Country
WHERE 
 [Country].[CountryPhoneLength] IN [Param].[PhoneLengthConfiguration]
```

If there is anyway to do this even not in this same way or method. That would be great. I have tried doing in this way at send an error that there is bad syntax

Comment: I don't think this is structured well. You'd be better off having multiple rows in a single table corresponding to multiple values. If you want to do it this way either use a LIKE clause or a regular expression.

Comment: yes this is possible. When you have a specific error message, you should post your statement and the error message. That makes it way easier to help you.

Comment: You need to use a subquery and correct cast to do that.

Comment: Another approach would be dynamic sql.

Answer (score 1):

you should make your data type uniform in order to ensure that you are comparing them in the right way. Ex.

```
SELECT column_name FROM Country
WHERE 
CAST([Country].[CountryPhoneLength] AS NVARCHAR(1)) IN
(SELECT CAST([Param].[PhoneLengthConfiguration] AS NVARCHAR(1)) FROM [Param])
```

Which is the same as:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM Country C
INNER JOIN Param P ON
                      CAST(P.PhoneLengthConfiguration AS NVARCHAR(1)) =  
                      CAST(C.CountryPhoneLength AS NVARCHAR(1))
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this would work unless I'm misreading the problem.  Casting the `PhoneLengthConfig` column to 1 character will give you `(` in all cases.  ie `SELECT CAST('(9,8)' as NVARCHAR(1))`

Comment: not actually, values in `PhoneLengthConfig` seems to be integers like 9, 8 not '(9,8)', so it would cast them as nvarchar in order to compare with the countryphonelength (i assume) nvarchar type.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT P.[PhoneLengthConfiguration, C.[CountryPhoneLength] FROM Country c
WHERE CAST([Country].[CountryPhoneLength] AS NVARCHAR(1)) IN
(SELECT P.[PhoneLengthConfiguration FROM [Param] P
 WHERE CAST(P.PhoneLengthConfiguration AS NVARCHAR(1)) =  CAST(C.CountryPhoneLength AS NVARCHAR(1)))
```